# The tagged parameter does not work with multiple tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, tags

Take these two API calls:

- http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions?tagged=php;rant
- http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/tagged/php;rant

A couple of problems:

1. Shouldn't they return the same thing? The first call doesn't return anything.
2. If they **should** return the same thing, why do we have two separate calls that do the same thing?

Comment: Any word on this one?

Comment: I'm using tagged filter too and it does not work http://stackprinter.appspot.com/topvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.