# Parameter `tagged` in `search/advanced` seems to use `AND` instead of `OR`

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, documentation, search, api-v2.1

It seems that `search/advanced` has the same problem as in "[The tagged parameter does not work with multiple tags](https://stackapps.com/questions/652/the-tagged-parameter-does-not-work-with-multiple-tags)" question.

When I select `c#; .net` I only get results tagged both `c#` and `.net`:
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=c%23;.net&site=stackoverflow

Comment: It's just the advanced search.  [Regular search uses OR logic as documented](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#page=859&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=c%23%3B.net&filter=!7DsGINP8aeQGI&site=stackoverflow).

Comment: Advanced search is also documented to use OR/ANY though: "`tagged` - a semicolon delimited list of tags, of which _at least one_ will be present on all returned questions.".

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. I'd rather avoid making multiple queries to the advance search if at all possible. Was there any progress made on this?

Comment: 3 and half years ago and this is still a case on v2.2

Comment: There is now [a duplicate of this bug on MetaSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288451/the-tagged-parameter-in-search-advanced-stack-exchange-api-seems-to-be-applying).

Comment: Related report 6 to 8 years later: [Call to search/advanced is treating tagged as an AND search, not OR](https://stackapps.com/q/9156/78873)