# Call to search/advanced is treating tagged as an AND search, not OR

Tags: support, api

The docs for search/advanced (https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) have this to state about the `tagged` attribute:

"tagged - a semicolon delimited list of tags, of which at least one will be present on all returned questions."

I read that to imply that it's an OR search. However in my testing, it appears to be AND. So for example:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&accepted=true&tagged=php;coldfusion

Returns questions marked with both tags - but maybe that's luck. But if I add a third tag:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&accepted=true&tagged=php;coldfusion;music

It returns nothing.

Comment: I read it as OR too, but it is probably a bug with the documentation rather than that of the API - it does seem like the logic is actually AND indeed...

Comment: oh, seems like someone reported this back in 2013: [Parameter `tagged` in `search/advanced` seems to use `AND` instead of `OR](https://stackapps.com/q/4157/78873). This is likely a bug (as mentioned, likely in the docs, but may very well be that SE thinks everything works as expected)

Comment: Is there anything 'formal' I can do to report this as a bug?

Comment: Well, you can try the main Meta... Staff rarely visits down here as it seems. But I think it's been reported multiple times there too :) Here is a report from [this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359181/786798)... And this one [from 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288451/786798)...

Comment: So you can definitely join the venerable tradition of this bug being reported every couple of years and then completely ignored by the company :)